# How to configure multiple processing servers

Tags: xconnect, processing

I followed two below documentation articles to create multiple dedicated processing servers for interaction aggregation:

1. https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/processing/index.html
2. https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-management/index.html

But they didn't describe how to configure CM server when we want to have multiple processing servers.

With a processing server, I need to set serviceUrl param in Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config on CM server as below image :
[image]

Does anyone know how to configure multiple serviceUrls for multiple processing servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You should introduce load balancer that will serve as "point of contact" for CM server. It's URL will be used as ServiceUrl on CM server. Your two processing servers will be behind it and load balancer will switch traffic to them as needed.

I think that Sitecore Documentation Team have forgotten to add "Load Balancer" icon in their nonetheless brilliant documentation for Sitecore 9 and xConnect:

[image]

More information can be found here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/scaling-scenarios/scale-horizontally/index.html#multiple-processing-instances

I have already contacted docsite@sitecore.net with a question regarding this.

Comment: Can you help me with the latest question ?

Comment: You should create new question and link this one as it is now completely different question.

Answer (score 3):

Hello excellent community folks - you don't strictly need a load balancer; you can choose a processing server for the CM to connect to. The CM->Processing connection is only needed to kick off reporting rebuild. That said, I understand that if Processing servers are being added/removed/changed, you don't want to just cross your fingers and hope that the CM has a Processing server to connect to when you need it! I will update that doc/s.

(Edit: verified by the Processing developer a few minutes ago. Some extra info for anyone that happens upon this page; communication between multiple Processing instances happens via the Processing Tasks database)